# CreateJS - Issue loading sounds in IE11

Tags: createjs, soundjs, preloadjs

I've run across a weird issue with sound file loading in IE11. I have a manifest of about a dozen images and then about 8 sound files. What's happening is versions of IE11 that have even the slightest modifications in the security settings are hanging up when trying to load the sound files. No errors, it just hangs. Any ideas?

Code below. Working fine in Chrome, Safari, FireFox and most IEs. Just some instances it loading everything up until the sounds and then it just stops.

```
var imagePath = "Game/images/";
var audioPath = "Game/sounds/";
manifest = [
    { src: imagePath + "BG.png", id: "bgImg" },
    { src: imagePath + "Game-Sign.png", id: "gameSign" },
    { src: imagePath + "Start-Title.png", id: "startTitle" },
    { src: imagePath + "Start-Button-Sprite.png", id: "btnStart" },
    { src: imagePath + "Continue-Button-Sprite.png", id: "btnContinue" },
    { src: audioPath + "clunk01.mp3", id: "sndClunk01" },
    { src: audioPath + "clunk02.mp3", id: "sndClunk02" },
    { src: audioPath + "clunk03.mp3", id: "sndClunk03" }
];

 var queue;
 queue = new createjs.LoadQueue(true);
 queue.installPlugin(createjs.Sound);
 createjs.Sound.alternateExtensions = ["ogg"];
 queue.addEventListener("complete", handleComplete);
 queue.loadManifest(manifest);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code looks fine.  There were some bugs in handle errors in the 0.6.0 versions, can you try [SoundJS-Next](https://github.com/CreateJS/SoundJS) with [PreloadJS-Next](https://github.com/CreateJS/PreloadJS) and let me know if that fixes the hanging issue.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That looks like it took care of it. It's no longer hanging up during the load process. The sounds don't play because of the changes in IE's security settings, but it's no longer breaking on load :)

Comment: Oh, by the way, what was the bug and fix you guys implemented? And should I just use these 'Next' versions in production? Thanks!

Comment: You can look at the [versions](https://github.com/CreateJS/SoundJS/blob/master/VERSIONS.txt) file for any of the repos to see fixes that have been implemented.
In this case, HTMLAudioLoader did not have a proper listener for errors which was added to a base class.

Next versions are stable and can be used, but obviously lack the advantages of being on a CDN and are continuously evolving until the next release.

Comment: My issue was that some sounds were playing but not all sounds in a specific version of IE 11 on Windows 7. Using SoundJS-Next sorted this issue out for me.